# How to access value in vary property key object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

i have object response from api in format

```
res = {
propid1:{data:resobj1},
propid2:{data:resobj2},
...
}
e.g.
res = {
2343434:{data:resobj},
67958:{data:resobj},
...
}
```

but propid1 is vary at run time, what is best way to access each data:resobj?

ps. propids is known(also vary) before api request like this

```
pid=[proid1,proid2,...]
```

thanks,

Comment: You can use `for..in` and iterate `res`..

Comment: `for...in` loop over the properties or access using `Object.keys`?

Comment: Here is the link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object

Comment: thanks, i'm new for javascript/typescript. at first, i try access with res.pid[i] and get error, now i change to res[pid[i]] and it work fine. don't know why but thanks anyway.